# Wordpress Contact Foprm 7

Tags: php, wordpress, php7, wordpress-plugin

estoy intentando crear un tag, pero cuando pongo [clock] no me funciona. Saben porque? Gracias!

class-rncf.php

```
private function define_admin_hooks() {

    $plugin_admin = new Rncf_Admin( $this->get_plugin_name(), $this->get_version() );

    $this->loader->add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', $plugin_admin, 'enqueue_styles' );
    $this->loader->add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', $plugin_admin, 'enqueue_scripts' );
    $this->loader->add_action( 'wpcf7_init', $plugin_admin, 'rnfc_init' );

}
```

class-rncf-admin.php

```
public function rnfc_init(){
    add_action( 'wpcf7_init', 'custom_add_form_tag_clock' );

    function custom_add_form_tag_clock() {
        wpcf7_add_form_tag( 'clock', 'custom_clock_form_tag_handler' ); // "clock" is the type of the form-tag
    }

    function custom_clock_form_tag_handler( $tag ) {
        return date_i18n( get_option( 'time_format' ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué error da? En Wordpress, seguro que pones el código en modo texto plano. Parece que después de Guttenberg hay cierta confusión y errores. Si usas shortcodes por ejemplo, asegúrate de poner el editor en modo código, no en modo visual.

Comment: No tengo ningun error. Cuando pongo el tag en el contact form me lo imprime igual [clock] tendria que imprimir la fecha. El contact form funciona y envia el correo

Comment: ¿Revisaste que pones el shortcode `[clock]` estando en modo código?. Si estás en modo visual no lo asume como un shortcode.

Comment: Pero el editor de contact form no no tiene modo visual. Lo puedes ver aqui como lo tengo https://ibb.co/BT3HwJK

Comment: ¿Tu plugin y tu Wordpress están actualizados? Convendría que actives el modo debug de Wordpress temporalmente para que puedas ver lo que está ocurriendo.